# Images sent over iMessages are low quality

Tags: iphone

I capture images via iphone camera and attach to iMessages. When I send those over iMessages if it is using data image quality is very low.

For an example.

5 MB taken image once it is sent over iMessages using data is 107KB

Please note that **low image quality is always switched off**.

If I send over WiFi original image is received by other party.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solutions after trying for several times. Finally.

Following need to take place to send **full quality image** taken via **iMessages**.

- Low quality image mode should be switched off
- Enable 4G without 3G
- Turn off low power mode

Comment: thanks for sharing, but I think this is pretty strange though. Why it should be so complicated to get a full quality image send via iMessage? I never discovered a problem regarding this. Image compression via WhatsApp is still disturbing for me but not over iMessage. Would you be so kind and give us more information about the circumstances regarding your issue? Did you experience this behavior everytime you sent a picture?

Comment: @pallox Yes I did ! The profession i am into I require full image with the Geo location but when the image is compressed I dont get those parameters. So it is a must to have the original image.

Comment: Ok I see. So following your steps is the only way you reach your goal? This could be interesting to forward this to Apple. I'm really irritated by that behavior. This can't be intended...

Comment: @pallox of course. That made me solve the issue I had.