# How can I stop my iPhone camera roll pictures from converting to .heic format when sent using iMessages?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, messages, heic

I’m using iPhone 13 pro max on iOS 15.4.1. I have camera formats setting on “most compatible”. When I take a picture with  iPhone, the picture is in .jpeg format. However when I share the same pictures via   iMessage, they are being converted to .heic format.

How do I stop this conversion and keep the photos in .jpeg format  while continuing to use iMessages to share photos ?  Here is screenshot of photo taken with phone, copied from camera roll to "Files" on iPhone, shows as .jpeg.

[image: pic 1]

Here is the same picture after I iMessage it to myself and drag and drop on desktop and File info.  Sorry I had screenshot it as I cant upload .heic.

[image: 2 pic]

[image: 3 pic]

Comment: There appear to be several setting in play. Have you tried [enabling low quality mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/317918/5472) to force a downsample?

Comment: Also, to clarify: are they converted inside your own photo library or just within Messages (so the receiver gets a heic picture)?

Comment: I have set the low quality mode with no affect. I take a picture and look at its format, its .jpeg. On the receiving end using iMessage, its .heic

Comment: If you share from Photos library there is “Options” on top of screen under number of selected photos. Clicking on that opens options window where are options: Automatic, Individual Photo and iCloud Link. Description below these options state that with Messages Automatic selects best format based on file size and number of items. So you can try Individual Photo, as it can be assumed that by selecting this option automatic conversion will not take place.

Comment: The "All Options Data" I see is just a toggle on/off.  I see the option under the number of selected photos to share.  I do not have Automatic, Individual Photo and iCloud Link.  I do not use iCloud photos.  I did toggle it on for the next test of which I will post.  The results were weird - when I save a photo to Files folder on my phone then share it via iMessage it stays .jpeg.  Straight from camera roll to iMessage then send, it converts to .heic.

Comment: I can't replicate conversion problem. I took photo in .jpeg format, shared from Photos to Messages and sent to myself. After drag-and-drop to macOS desktop it was still .jpeg.

Comment: its weird!  Thats the same thing I got from the apple discussions board I posted on.  Very odd. out of curiosity, what OS are you on?

Comment: I tried this too and it stays .jpeg.  I go to iMessages on my computer, select my thread and keep the cursor in the typing field.  Then go to Messages, file, import from phone and I take a pic on my phone. It stays .jpeg after I drop it on the desktop.  Just as an aside.  It seems the file are getting converted on the send.